# AlertDialog with Timeout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to create an AlertDialog with a timer in it. Basically I want the dialog to disappear if the user doesn't make a decision on the buttons that are in the dialog after 30 seconds. I can create a dialog using an AlertDialog builder, but it seems like I cannot update the text using the .setMessage() method after the .show() method has been executed.

Any ideas on what I should do?

So in the code below if I run the .setMessage() method after the .show() method I see nothing. This is telling me that I cannot update the text in the dialog box in real time.

```
// Create the alert dialog with a alert builder.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm Settings Change")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.setMessage("test");
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have previously called `setMessage()` at least once prior to calling `show()` in order to be able to call it again afterwards.  You can set it to an empty value or to a temporary one, then update it later:

```
alert.setMessage("test");
alert.show();
...
alert.setMessage("test again");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend inflating a custom Dialog from XML so that you can get a handle to the TextView (or whatever) that you want to change in your code. It's really easy:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: This looks like it would work, but the answered offered by dave. c works as well. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ProgressDialog:

```
public Context ioContext;
private ProgressDialog ioProgressDialog;


ioProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ioContext, "", "This is my dialog!", true);
ioProgressDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='black'>" + isMensaje + "</font>"));
```